# Extracting zip file fails giving error need PK compat. v5.1

Tags: 11.10, extract, zip

I have a password protected zip file which was created in Windows. When I am trying to extract the same file under Ubuntu I get the error `need PK compat. v5.1 (can do v4.6)`. Any idea how to proceed?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1416364) you can use 7z for this. First install **p7zip-full** package with:

```
sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
```

Then either use the GUI or extract the archive with this command:

```
7z e /path/to/file
```

or

```
7z x /path/to/file
```

(second one preserves directory structure).

Comment: very good that also the GUI (file-roller) understand to use p7zip if installed!

Comment: This fixed the problem for me. Note that even though this fixes file-roller, the `unzip` tool will continue to report this error, so you'll have to use `7z` for normal zip/unzip.

Answer (score -3):

Fix zip file by the use of fixing broken zip file missing parts

Item http://www.fixbrokenzipfile.zipfilefix.com will give you the conception how to handle the issue

Comment: The link is broken...

Comment: No, it's not a broken zip file...